# rpc call to R function is not responding in case of OpenCPU cloud server, although it is working fine in single user server

Tags: r, opencpu

I am using OpenCPU for my R project web interface.
the project is working fine and i'm able to get results as expected on my local machine (single user server).

then I deployed my project on VM and it didn't work.
On VMs the R functions are working properly from R prompt. The single user is also working and i'm able to query it using cURL. but the public server always hangs-up and time-out after 90 secs

other points to note:

1. sample projects like tvscore and gitstats are working fine on cloud server as well
2. my project is based on rJava. I have had trouble setting it up but finally it worked on single user server.
3. I have tried AWS EC2 t2.micro. I have also tried Google n1 (1-CPU 3.75 GB) and n2 (2-CPU 7.5 GB) instances.
4. I didn't change anything in my /etc/opencpu/server.conf

the error that I'm getting on failure:

`R call did not return within 90 seconds. Terminating process.`

my server.conf

```
{
    "enable.api.library": true,
    "enable.api.apps": true,
    "enable.api.bioc": true,
    "enable.api.cran": true,
    "enable.api.gist": true,
    "enable.api.github": true,
    "enable.api.user": true,
    "enable.api.tmp": true,
    "enable.cors" : true,
    "enable.post.code": true,
    "error.showcall": true,
    "gist.cache": 300,
    "github.cache": 86400,
    "cran.cache": 86400,
    "public.url" : "https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu",
    "smtp.server" : "localhost",
    "httpcache.post": 300,
    "httpcache.lib": 86400,
    "httpcache.git": 900,
    "httpcache.gitapi": 120,
    "httpcache.tmp": 86400,
    "httpcache.cran": 86400,
    "httpcache.static": 31536000,
    "httpcache.bioc": 31536000,
    "key.length" : 9,
    "appspaths": "/usr/local/lib/opencpu/apps-library",
    "repos": "http://cran.rstudio.com",
    "rlimit.as": 2e9,
    "rlimit.fsize": 1e8,
    "rlimit.nproc": 50,
    "timelimit.get": 600,
    "timelimit.post": 90,
    "timelimit.webhook": 900,
    "preload": ["ggplot2", "lattice"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the value of "timelimit.post" in server.conf. Default is 90 seconds, apparently you need more.